# How do you run snowplow-bigquery-loader?

Tags: snowplow

Where do you find/make/use the command:

```
./snowplow-bigquery-mutator \
    listen      # Can be "init" to create empty table
    --config $CONFIG \
    --resolver $RESOLVER \
```

Given by the snowplow-bigquery-loader documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run it from a GCP compute instance. Ensure that both your `--config` and `--resolver` arguments are base64 encoded json arrays provided in the examples.

Comment: Aha that must be the issue!!